# Help with Macbook and 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, macbook

What is the latest version of Ubuntu I can run with working Wifi on my Macbook 4,1(early 2008)?

I dual booted my Mac OSX Lion alongside 12.10 but can't figure how to get the wireless to work. Ergo, I downgraded to 10.10 for now.

Is 10.10 the latest version I can have on my Macbook with working Wifi, or is there another?

Am i simply missing a terminal code to fix the drivers?

Comment: whats the wireless chip? you can check it out with "lspci | grep Network"

Answer (score 1):

i finally got this to work so can confirm that 12.10 as working isight/wireless on macbook 4,1

Comment: Well done - can you expand your answer with what you did so that others can benefit?